# How to show that this series diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{6}+\frac{3}{11}+\frac{4}{18}+\frac{5}{27}+\dots$

I tried representing this in a sequence from and This is what I ended up with :

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{n}{2n+1-a_n}$$

But couldn't end up anywhere

Comment: Hint: $\sum 2k+1 = n^2$

Comment: @Exodd Huh?  I don't see how that helps?

Comment: Your formula for the general term $a_{n+1}=\frac{n}{2n+1-a_n}$ is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint 
The sequence is $a_n=\frac{n}{n^2+2}$, try to compare with $\frac{1}{n+2}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you can also write $a_n=\frac{n}{n^2+2}$